# How do I name a result group in a Regex? (.Net)

Tags: .net, regex

How do I name a result group in a Regex? (.Net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<NAME>EXPRESSION) or (?'NAME'EXPRESSION)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<NameOfGroup>[a-z]*)
```

Use the ? syntax like in the sample above.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<first>group)(?'second'group).
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<name>.*)
```

Substitute  with whatever you want to call your group. whatever follow is the regular expression you expect to parse and match the result to the group.

See my post this morning on example how to parse a file list for name and number index

[How to get files from 1 to n in a particular pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307865/how-to-get-files-from-1-to-n-in-a-particular-pattern/2308012#2308012)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<name>subpattern)
```

Where < name > is the name of the group, and subpattern is the code
For e.g.

```
(?<words>\w+)
```

same thing as `\w+` but named it "words"